# Distinguished field promotion against a TypedPolling generated schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I'm trying to promote a field using Distinguished promotion so that I can filter the value on the initializing Receive shape by a specific value.
The schema has been generated as a TypedPolling Envelope schema, and has been configured and setup to debatch on a MaxOccurs of 1.

Whenever I go into the Receive filter though, I can't find the Message/Distinguished field. I've also looked against Message Assignment and Expression editor shapes, but it doesn't appear anywhere.
I've checked that the shape and message are both referencing the correct schema.
I've also tried saving, refreshing, building and restarting VS, with no joy on any occasion.

[image: Setting the required field in the schema to Distinguished]

[image: Unable to locate the distinguished property here]

Comment: For those voting to close this not being about programming, it is programming related. BizTalk Development, including building Orchestrations is programming, just using a GUI interface that will generate code. @Ken-White

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For message filtering (subscribing) it needs to be a Promoted Property, rather than a Distinguished Property (as what you have defined).  So you need to have a Property Schema and add that field in the Property Fields.

[image: BizTalk Promotion dialogue]

Distinguished properties can only be used in an Orchestration assignment shapes, and not for subscribing in the initialization Receive shape, as they aren't promoted.  In the assignment shape you would reference it by starting of with the message name, then a dot, and it would then bring up options for referencing the distinguished field. But you can't use this in the receive shape.

Comment: Thanks as always @Dijkgraaf! I had a suspicion it was related to property promotion over distinguished promotion, but the wording on the MSDN site page and others that I'd read implied that *any* in-orchestration filter was for Distinguished (so I assumed that a receive shapes filter was part of that).
When you phrase it the way you have, it makes perfect sense. Cheers again